# How can I setup Yii Boilerplate?

Tags: php, yii, boilerplate

I have seen lots of pages about Yii Boilerplate setup like: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/374/yiiboilerplate-setup-a-professional-project-structure-in-seconds/.
Is there any step by step instruction about creating a new basic YiiBoilerPlate app or maybe I am totally wrong about it!?!?!

Comment: Even I can't understand how to setup Boilerplate. Did you set it up already? Show us. Thanks! :)

Comment: I Couldn't setup Boilerplate, So I just used YiiBooster for my project. While there is not many other people complaining about its setup, I guess my brain doesn't have a specific chipset (or more) to understand setup process!

Answer (score 2):

Just build your app to fit your needs remembering to keep project specific files in separate folders, separate from base application components, like common extensions. I highly recommend using modules. You can have for example user management module with login, logout, profile etc. functionality, and depending on concrete project requirements just drop in more modules.

Mentioned boilerplate is more complex than standard Yii setup. There is one thing i really dont like, is that mudules are in both frontend and backend, and according to yii philosofy, module should be like mini application, so from this boilerplate seems that one should build separate mini apps for frontend and backend... But it is just a taste what you feel better.

If you are new i recommend standard setup, but using modules from beginning. Modules are something like mini app, which can operate on it's own. This way you can build your portfolio of modules, and then when doing some new project you can compose it much quicker and sturdier. A bit more tricki might be interoperability between modules, but thats a whole different story.

Comment: thanks for your useful comments, but how can I setup first YiiBoilerPlate application? Any cmd command?

Comment: For this boilreplate everything is mentioned on wiki, just get it from github https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBoilerplate

Answer (score 2):

You should refer following article.

http://myprogrammingtut.blogspot.in/2013/04/step-by-step-setup-yiiboilerplate.html

which worked for me :)

Hope it'll help you.